# SQL Server - How to speed up the query?

Tags: sql-server, query-performance

I have written a SQL query as below

```
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE USP_GET_CUSTOMER_WITH_BALANCE1
    (@CUSTOMER_NAME VARCHAR(256))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @FISCAL_YEAR INT;

    SELECT @FISCAL_YEAR = (SELECT Id FROM tbl_Fiscal 
                           WHERE status = 1);

    ;WITH CTE_CUSTOMER AS 
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM tbl_cust_mast 
        WHERE cust_name LIKE '%' + @CUSTOMER_NAME + '%'
    )
    SELECT 
        SUM(m.Balance) AS 'Balance', 
        m.Id, m.ledger, m.cust_name, m.BillDate, m.BillNo 
    FROM (
         SELECT 
             cm.Id, cm.ledger, 
             ISNULL((CASE WHEN t.Fiscal = @FISCAL_YEAR THEN SUM(t.Debit - t.Credit) ELSE 0 END), 0) AS 'Balance',
             cm.cust_name, 
             ISNULL(s.CreatedDate, NULL) AS 'BillDate', 
             ISNULL(s.inv_no, NULL) AS 'BillNo' 
         FROM 
             CTE_CUSTOMER cm
         LEFT OUTER JOIN 
             tbl_Transaction t ON cm.ledger = t.ledger_Code
         LEFT OUTER JOIN (
              SELECT * 
              FROM (
                  SELECT 
                       cust_id,
                       inv_no,
                       CreatedDate, 
                       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_id ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC) rn 
                   FROM 
                       tbl_salesmast
              ) q
              WHERE rn = 1
        ) s ON cm.Id = s.cust_id
        GROUP BY 
            cm.Id,
            cm.cust_name,
            cm.ledger,
            s.CreatedDate,
            s.inv_no,
            t.Fiscal
   ) m
   GROUP BY 
       m.Id,
       m.ledger,
       m.cust_name,
       m.BillDate,
       m.BillNo
END;

GO
EXEC USP_GET_CUSTOMER_WITH_BALANCE1 'cash'
```

When I run this query the result comes after only 5-10 second. How to optimize this query so that result will output instantly.

For your information the table `tbl_Transaction` contains only 43222 rows and `tbl_salesmast` contains only 9619 rows. Here is the execution plan of the query

[image]

Comment: The sub-queries will be what's killing you. Try assigning some of them to temporary tables and see if it helps

Comment: The `s` part could by simplified `OUTER APPLY (
       SELECT TOP(1) ts.inv_no, ts.CreatedDate FROM tbl_salesmast ts
        WHERE cm.Id = ts.cust_id
        ORDER BY ts.CreatedDate DESC ) s`

Comment: @Serg excecute on same time

Comment: The formatting is killing performance in your ability to debug and decipher this. Don't be scared to use some white space so you can see what is going on. Your cte is using a leading wildcard. That is not going to help performance. But then in your main query you have nested subqueries at least 4 layers deep. My guess is this could be done with a single query from the get go.

Comment: In order to offer any actual help thought we would need table definitions, indexes, sample data. And to help with your execution you should use https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: if invno and billdate are incremental, would the latest record always have the max of each?

Comment: Please also show the full table and index definitions for the relevant tables

Comment: It is difficult to understand what your query does with the repetition, the outer joins, the strange conditional sum (which looks highly suspicious), the mutation of FK column names. The `@fiscal_year` variable seems like a simple flag but perhaps it denotes a specific fiscal year - difficult to know given the query that sets it. I suspect you don't need all those outer joins. Suggest you start over and start with summing only the transaction rows you need. Use of cryptic alias names are not helpful either.

Answer (score 0):

Without being able to see the entire query plan, I would start by trying to clean up the below CTE. See if it's possible to remove the leading '%' in the LIKE statement. Being the only line in the WHERE clause, this will always produce a full table scan.

```
;WITH CTE_CUSTOMER AS 
(
SELECT * 
    FROM tbl_cust_mast 
    WHERE cust_name LIKE '%' + @CUSTOMER_NAME + '%'
)
```